# Adding images to type and delete effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm implementing a type and delete effect with the code below. Current code successfully shows 4 sentences one by one, but I'd like to add images at the end of each sentence.

So after the first sentence is typed, I'd like to show 3 images also one by one (not at the same time) next to the first sentence. (update: to clarify, I'd like each image to appear in the same exact place as other images) Then the first sentence gets deleted, and second sentence gets typed, and next to the second sentence, another set of images will be shown one by one (not at the same time). Then the second sentence gets deleted so on.... Note that I'll have 12 different images in total.

It seems that I'd need to insert a new function between those lines:

```js
if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {

clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
```

but am having a hard time actually writing the code. Help would be appreciated.

html:

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="text"></div><div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var _CONTENT = [ "This is the first sentence", "I'm the second sentence", "Third sentence goes here", 
"I'm a fourth sentence" ];

var _PART = 0;


var _PART_INDEX = 0;


var _INTERVAL_VAL;


var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");


function Type() { 
var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
_ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
_PART_INDEX++;

if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {

    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    setTimeout(function() {
        _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
    }, 1000);

}
}

function Delete() {
var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
_ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
_PART_INDEX--;

if(text === '') {
    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

    if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
        _PART = 0;
    else
        _PART++;
    _PART_INDEX = 0;

    setTimeout(function() {
        _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    }, 200);
}
}

_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in css fade in and fade out, hide the images by default, and add a showing class to css.

When fading in, add the showing class. When fading out, remove the showing class when the fade out ends.

```js
var _CONTENT = [ "This is the first sentence", "I'm the second sentence", "Third sentence goes here", 
"I'm a fourth sentence" ];

const IMAGE_URLS = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/wftMn.jpg?s=96&g=1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFsyb.png?s=96&g=1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYIVC.png?s=96&g=1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/zweIW.png?s=96&g=1','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d84b558fd67be10d5a718fb94231909d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a2d818d801ce38a33807f68fdd92043a?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/52a2ffb44b1c11ab9001cb67e0a0021c?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG','https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIt1g.png?s=96&g=1','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3f8912af19fe86b7b34a0b011a962460?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a235706e3d81b614acaec3368edfea4b?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG','https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxeUf.jpg?s=96&g=1','https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xczZ.jpg?s=96&g=1'];

const IMAGES = IMAGE_URLS.map((url, index) =>
{
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', url);
  img.classList.add('anim'+((index%3)+1));
  img.classList.add('fadeOut');
  document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
  return img;
});


var _PART = 0;


var _PART_INDEX = 0;


var _INTERVAL_VAL;


var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");


function Type() { 
var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
_ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
_PART_INDEX++;

if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {
    let imgIndexBase = _PART*3;
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn', 'show');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.add('fadeIn', 'show');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.add('fadeIn', 'show');
    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    setTimeout(function() {
        _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
    }, 1000);

}
}

function Delete() {
var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
_ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
_PART_INDEX--;

if(text === '') {
    let imgIndexBase = _PART*3;
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeIn');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('fadeIn');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.remove('fadeIn');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.add('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.add('fadeOut');
    
    setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('invisible'); }, 300);
    setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.add('invisible'); }, 400);
    
    setTimeout(function() 
    { 
      IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('show', 'invisible');
      IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('show', 'invisible');
      IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.remove('show'); 
    }, 500);

    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

    if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
        _PART = 0;
    else
        _PART++;
    _PART_INDEX = 0;

    setTimeout(function() {
        _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    }, 200);
}
}

_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```css
img
{
  display:none;
}

img.invisible
{
  visibility: hidden;
}

img.show
{
  display:inline;
}

img.anim1
{
  animation-duration: 300ms;
}

img.anim2
{
  animation-duration: 600ms;
}

img.anim3
{
  animation-duration: 900ms;
}


.fadeIn
{
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn 
{
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeOut
{
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@keyframes fadeOut 
{
 0% {opacity: 1;}
 100% {opacity: 0; display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="text"></div><div id="cursor"><div id="images"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton! just tried implementing, and it looks like 3 images appear at the same time. would it be possible to make the images appear one by one, and not at the same time? btw i'm sometimes seeing a blinking effect, like those images show for a fraction of a second when they aren't supposed to be there. much appreciate your help

Comment: They're not appearing at the same time. If you look at the css they're appearing after 300ms, 400ms and 500ms, which may be too quick to really discern a difference, but since there's only a second to do the fade in, I made it quick. Play with the values until you get ones you're happy with.

Comment: @user130176 I've stretched the times to 300, 600, 900, so you should see the difference now

Comment: I was able to tweak your code to achieve the desired effect (it turns out I wasn't super clear in my original post). Your help was *extremely* valuable. Thanks so much. One quick question: here's what I have now https://imgur.com/a/A26ccnK but whenever the image appears the whole line shifts. is there a quick fix? I applied display: flex to #container

Comment: @user130176 Glad to help. What you need to do is set the height of the text container to be the height of the tallest image.

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: @MattEllen Follow up on my prev question. Setting height of text container to be the height of the tallest image indeed makes text not move. It looks like this now : https://imgur.com/a/6tJ1NC1 but I'm trying to horizontally align text and image like this: https://imgur.com/a/iIIqRUQ   I tried   #conA #container {
    flex-direction: row;    
    align-items: center;   
  }  but it didn't work - would you know how to fix? pls feel free to post an answer here, i'll select answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669713/having-issues-with-vertical-alignment-flexbox-and-center-alignment

Comment: (you can ignore the second question there if you post there. thanks so much for your help)