# Having issues with vertical alignment (Flexbox) and center alignment

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm using javascript to display dynamic text and image, but having trouble with formatting.

1. I'm using display: flex to put text and image next to each other, but am having trouble horizontally aligning them. Right now, it looks like:

[image]

But I'd like to horizontally align them so that it becomes:

[image]

I've tried the following,  but this didn't work

```
  #conA #container {
    display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;    
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;   
  }
```

Update:

Implementing the following code but NOT setting the height of #heroText and #images the same

```
  #conA #container {
        display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;    
        justify-content: center; 
        align-items: center;   
      }
```

does center text and images horizontally when both are present. However, once the images disappear, the text jumps. Here's how it's behaving   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWutg.jpg   I'd like the text to not move when images disappear

Once I set the heights of #heroText and #images the same, it then turns to this:
[image]

2. I'm also looking to center the whole text+image in the parent div (#conA, which takes up full screen 100vh).  I tried the following:

   ```
     #conA  {
     position: relative;  
      }

      #conA #container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
   ```

But it looks odd b/c text keeps moving/jumping depending on whether there's an image displayed.
So when there's no image, it looks like:

[image]

When when images appear, text moves to left so that the whole thing becomes centered:

[image]

How can I fix the position of text here? I'd like the whole thing is centered when there's an image. So when there's no image:

[image]

When there's an image:

[image]

html

```
<section id="conA">
<div id="container">
  <div id="heroText">
    <div id="text-fixed">I'm a fixed text</div>
    <div id="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="images"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

css

```
#conA {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}


#conA #container {
  margin: 0;
}


#conA #text {
  display: initial;
  border-right: 3px solid #56525E;
}


  #heroText {
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 800px;
  }


  #conA #container {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
  }

  #heroText {
    height: 400px;
  }


  #conA #images {
    height: 400px;
} 



#conA img
{
  display:none;
  height: 400px;
}

#conA img.invisible
{
  visibility: hidden;
}

#conA img.show
{
  display:inline;
}

#conA img.anim1
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}

#conA img.anim2
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}

#conA img.anim3
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}


.fadeIn
{
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn 
{
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeOut
{
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

javascript code for dynamic display of text and image

```
// List of sentences
var _CONTENT = [ "I'm the first sentence.", "I'm the second sentence."
, "I'm the third sentence.", "I'm the fourth sentence." ];


var IMAGE_URLS = ['img/image1.png', 'img/image2.jpg', 'img/image3.png', 'img/image1.png','img/image2.png','img/image3.png', 'img/image4.png','img/image5.png'];

var IMAGES = jQuery.map(IMAGE_URLS, function (url, index){ 
  var img = document.createElement('img'); 
  img.setAttribute('src', url); 
  img.classList.add('anim'+((index%2)+1)); 
  img.classList.add('fadeOut'); 
  document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img); 
  return img;
}); 

// Current sentence being processed
var _PART = 0;

// Character number of the current sentence being processed 
var _PART_INDEX = 0;

// Holds the handle returned from setInterval
var _INTERVAL_VAL;

// Element that holds the text
var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");

// Implements typing effect
function Type() { 
  var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX++;

  // If full sentence has been displayed then start to delete the sentence after some time
  if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {

  var imgIndexBase = _PART*2;
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('show'); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut'); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('show'); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('show'); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.remove('fadeOut'); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.remove('show'); }, 3000);




    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
    }, 4000);

  }
}




// Implements deleting effect
function Delete() {
  var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX--;

  // If sentence has been deleted then start to display the next sentence
  if(text === '') {
 


    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

    // If last sentence then display the first one, else move to the next
    if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
      _PART = 0;
    else
      _PART++;
    _PART_INDEX = 0;

    // Start to display the next sentence after some time
    setTimeout(function() {
      _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    }, 500);
  }
}

// Start the typing effect on load
_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

Comment: can't you just hide the image using `display: none;`

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy I'm not trying to hide the image

Comment: Have you tried you use `align-items` only? That way, when there is no image, your text will be aligned to the left. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) for a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

See example below using flex CSS. First section with image, second section with no images in `.images` div.

There is a lot to explain with flex, but it is super powerful when it comes to dynamic layout. Hope this gets you on the right track.

Also you need to relax on your `id` attribute usage, valid html only allow single usage of an `id` attribute value. Use `class` attribute for multiple instances, and `id` for single usage instances.

`id` attribute value should only ever be used once, never multiple times.

```css
BODY {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}

SECTION .container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: initial;
  min-height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

SECTION .container .hero-text {
  width: 50%;
  background: cyan;
}

SECTION .container .images {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

SECTION .container .images IMG {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <div class="text-fixed">I'm a fixed text</div>
      <div class="text">And I am loving life :)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <div class="text-fixed">I'm a fixed text</div>
      <div class="text">And I am loving life :)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
      <!-- no images -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks but i'd like the text NOT to move i.e. text stays in the same position whether there're images or not

Comment: See update answer, changed `SECTION .container .images`  css `max-width: 50%;` to `width: 50%;`

Comment: I think formatting gets weird once image gets added/deleted...  i've tried your code here https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminana77/xr60p9ae/1/   but still having the same problem. would you have insights here?

Comment: So when the sentences type out, do you want a set of images to change for that particular sentence? Do the images need to be in a carousel? I've started something by moving your content and images into the same object, I just need to know how you want it to work exactly https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qy9grh7b/34/

Comment: Sorry for the very slow reply here. Here's what I'd like it to behave  https://imgur.com/a/kr7jcSi  (yes, i want the images to change, no need to be in a carousel, just side by side). Thank you so much for your help